# Problem with an if statement in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I just started shell scripting, and I need to check if a file exists so I used command :

```sh
    if [[-e "./doc/issues/$1.md" ]];
```

But the command seems to be invalid.

Does anybody knows why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to put a whitespace before -e, try :

```py
if [[ -e "./doc/issues/$1.md" ]];
```

Comment: The reason the space is required is that `[[` is not mere syntax: it is (essentially) a **command**, and like every command, it needs a space to separate it from its arguments.

Comment: Spaces are critical parts of shell syntax; there are places where they're required (like between `[[` and `-e` -- and also `-e` and the filename, and the filename and `]]`), and places where they're not allowed (like around the `=` in an assignment), but very few places where they're optional. When copying an example, be sure to copy the spacing along with everything else.

Comment: Or in other words: shell scripts work with words. 2 words are usually separated by any number of space, tabs or linefeeds. quotes are used to create words with included spaces/tabs. So `[[-e` is one word without special meaning. I contrast, `[[ -e` are 2 words. `[[` opens a condition test mode and `-e` is a condition that accepts the next word as param.